# DefaultAccountAdapter and DefaultSocialAccountAdapter?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I tried the following to specific different signup flows for users who sign up via social accounts (facebook) and those that sign up via traditional login.

```
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
class NormalAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        if request.user.last_login == request.user.date_joined:
            return 'survey/'
        else:
            return '/results/'

class CorporateAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        if request.user.last_login == request.user.date_joined:
            return 'corporate/survey/'
        else:
            return 'corporate/results/'
```

But even if you log in with facebook, it calls DefaultAccountAdapter's get_login_redirect_url instead of DefaultSocialAccountAdapter's.

Answer (score 4):

Point the all auth plugin to the correct adapter classes! Add the following settings to your django app:

```
# project/settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'python.path.to.your.CorporateAdapter'

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER ='python.path.to.your.NormalAdapter'
```

Then save and reload the app (if you are on apache, just restart apache)